# Image transition (?) in CSS/HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I am trying to get my image to grow, fade and have text come up from the bottom. Is there any way to do this? I have tried variations of ".grow:hover" but it is not working for me. I have been trying to get my images (which are in the bottom-sidebar divider) to do it. An example I found but have not been able to duplicate can be found [here](http://designshack.net/tutorialexamples/PhotoWall/fade.html)

Here's my HTML and CSS.

```css
/* ===========================
======= Body style ======== 
=========================== */

body {
  background-image: url('images/image.png');
  color: #000305;
  font-size: 87.5%;
  /* Base font size: 14px */
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', Trebuchet, 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.429;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: left;
}
.body {
  clear: both;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 70%;
}
/* ===========================
    ========= Headings ======== 
    =========================== */

h1 {
  font-size: 2.5em
}
h2 {
  font-size: 1.571em
}
/* 22px */

h3 {
  font-size: 1.429em
}
/* 20px */

h4 {
  font-size: 1.286em
}
/* 18px */

h5 {
  font-size: 1.143em
}
/* 16px */

h6 {
  font-size: 0.95em
}
/* 14px */

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.1;
  margin-bottom: .8em;
}
/* ===========================
    ======= Anchor style ====== 
    =========================== */

body {
  background-image: url('images/image.png');
  color: #000305;
  font-size: 87.5%;
  /* Base font size: 14px */
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', Trebuchet, 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.429;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: left;
}
a {
  outline: 0;
}
a img {
  border: 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:link,
a:visited {
  color: #CF5C3F;
  padding: 0 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.mainHeader nav {
  background: #666;
  font-size: 1.143em;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-left: -40px;
}
.mainHeader nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 430px;
}
.mainHeader nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.mainHeader nav a:link,
.mainHeader nav a:visited {
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 5px 23px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.mainHeader nav a:hover,
.mainHeader nav a:active,
.mainHeader nav .active a:link,
.mainHeader nav .active a:visited {
  color: #fff;
}
.mainHeader nav li a {
  background: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(#666666, #666666 41px, #FF9317 41px, #FF9317 82px);
  background: -moz-repeating-linear-gradient(#666666, #666666 41px, #FF9317 41px, #FF9317 82px);
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(#666666, #666666 41px, #FF9317 41px, #FF9317 82px);
  background-size: 100% 200%;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  -moz-transition: all 1s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
.mainHeader nav a:hover {
  background-position: 0px -40px;
}
.mainHeader nav ul li h1 {
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
/* ===========================
    ======= Content Area ====== 
    =========================== */

.mainContent {
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 25px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}
.topcontent {
  background-color: #EBE4DD;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 3% 5%;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
}
.bottomcontent {
  background-color: #EBE4DD;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 3% 5%;
}
.content {
  width: 68%;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}
.post-info {
  font-style: italic;
  color: #919191;
  font-size: 85%;
}
/* ===========================
    ======== Sidebar ========== 
    =========================== */

.top-sidebar,
.middle-sidebar,
.bottom-sidebar {
  width: 24%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 2%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #EBE4DD;
  padding: 2% 3%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}
/* ===========================
    ========= Footer ========== 
    =========================== */

.mainFooter {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  padding-left: 0;
  background-color: #666;
  border-radius: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius: 20px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
  color: #FFF;
}
.mainFooter p {
  width: 91%;
  margin: 2% auto;
}
/* ===========================
    ====== Miscellaneous ====== 
    =========================== */

@media only screen and (min-width: 150px) and (max-width: 780px) {
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type "text/css" href="styles.css" />
  <title>Craftd's Official Website</title>
</head>

<body class="body">
  <header class="mainHeader">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li class="active">
          <span> 
       <li><a href="file:///C:/Users/Blake/Desktop/Webpage/index.html">Home</a></li>
       <li><a href="file:///C:/Users/Blake/Desktop/Webpage/gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </span> 
          </div>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <br>
  <div class="mainContent">
    <div class="content">
      <article class="topcontent">
        <header>
          <h2><a href="#" rel="bookmark" title="Welcome!">Welcome!</a></h2>
        </header>

        <footer>
          <p class="post-info">Welcome to my Channel!</p>
        </footer>

        <content>
          <iframe width="580" height="300" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/oetU4zNP91o" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </content>

      </article>

      <article class="bottomcontent">

        <header>
          <h2><a href="#" rel="bookmark" title="First Post">First post</a></h2>
        </header>

        <footer>
          <p class="post-info"></p>
        </footer>

        <content>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dlior sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dliore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
            irure dlior in reprehenderit in vliuptate velit esse cillum dliore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Duis aute irure dlior in reprehenderit in vliuptate velit esse cillum dliore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
        </content>

      </article>
    </div>

    <aside class="top-sidebar">
      <article>
        <h2><center>Q & A's!</center></h2>
        <p>
          <ol>
            <h6>
     <li><i>What is your middle name?</i> Malosi.</li>
     <li><i>Where do you live?</i> Australia.</li>
     <li><i>What do you use to record?</i> Fraps, ands sometimes Camtasia.</li>
     <li><i>What consoles do you play?</i> Just XBox 360.</li>
     <li><i>What was your first ever game?</i> Mario Bros. on the GameBoy.</li>
    </p></ol></h6>
      </article>
    </aside>

    <aside class="middle-sidebar">
      <article>
        <h2><center>Latest News!</center></h2>
        <p><i><u><center>There are no new stories.</center></u></i>
        </p>
      </article>
    </aside>

    <aside class="bottom-sidebar">
      <article>
        <h2>Social Networks</h2>
        <a href="http://www.facebook.com/CraftdMC/">
          <img src="images/Facebook.png" alt="Facebook" width="64" height="64">
        </a>
        <a href="http://www.instagram.com/CraftdMC/">
          <img src="images/Instagram.png" alt="Instagram" width="64" height="64">
        </a>
        <a href="http://www.twitter.com/CraftdMC/">
          <img src="images/Twitter.png" alt="Twitter" width="64" height="64">
        </a>
      </article </aside>
  </div>
  <footer class="mainFooter">
    <p>Copyright &copy; 2014 <a href="http://craftd.com/">Craftd</a>
    </p>
  </footer>


  </center>
</body>

</HTML>
```

Comment: It would be easier for us to help if you add a [Fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/) or [Stack Snippet](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) to your post.

Comment: [I think you've posted the wrong code](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/3xt63prk/).

Comment: What do you mean wrong code? @chipChocolate.py

Comment: What I mean is, I don't understand where you want to apply that effect.

Comment: In the bottom-sidebar, where I have my Twitter, Instagram & Facebook logos with a link to my accounts on them. @chipChocolate.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `@keyframes` to do this. I've used some JavaScript code to add couple CSS rules to `.img:hover` when the animation ends.

```js
var imgs = document.getElementsByClassName('img');
var event = ['webkitAnimationEnd', 'animationend'];

for (i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < event.length; j++) {
    imgs[i].addEventListener(event[j], function() {
      var ss = document.styleSheets;
      for (k = 0; k < ss.length; k++) {
        var rules = ss[k];
        for (l = 0; l < rules.cssRules.length; l++) {
          var r = rules.cssRules[l];
          if (r.selectorText == ".img:hover") {
            r.style.backgroundSize = "170px 170px";
            r.style.backgroundPosition = "-10px -10px";
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}
.img {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/150/150/);
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-size: 150px 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 150px;
  color: transparent;
  font-size: 25px;
  -webkit-animation: shrink 0.5s 1;
  animation: shrink 0.5s 1;
  opacity: 1;
}
.img:hover {
  -webkit-animation: grow 0.5s 1;
  animation: grow 0.5s 1;
  opacity: 0.5;
  color: white;
}
@-webkit-keyframes grow {
  0% {
    background-size: 150px 150px;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    opacity: 1;
    color: transparent;
  }
  100% {
    background-size: 170px 170px;
    background-position: -10px -10px;
    opacity: 0.5;
    color: white;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes grow {
  0% {
    background-size: 150px 150px;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    opacity: 1;
    color: transparent;
  }
  100% {
    background-size: 170px 170px;
    background-position: -10px -10px;
    opacity: 0.5;
    color: white;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes shrink {
  0% {
    background-size: 170px 170px;
    background-position: -10px -10px;
    opacity: 0.5;
    color: white;
  }
  100% {
    background-size: 150px 150px;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    opacity: 1;
    color: transparent;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes shrink {
  0% {
    background-size: 170px 170px;
    background-position: -10px -10px;
    opacity: 0.5;
    color: white;
  }
  100% {
    background-size: 150px 150px;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    opacity: 1;
    color: transparent;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="img">Content</div>
  <div class="img">Content</div>
  <div class="img">Content</div>
  <div class="img">Content</div>
  <div class="img">Content</div>
  <div class="img">Content</div>
  <div class="img">Content</div>
  <div class="img">Content</div>
  <div class="img">Content</div>
  <div class="img">Content</div>
  <div class="img">Content</div>
  <div class="img">Content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for all your help, but I can't seem to get it to work. [This](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/eLnz2va2/2/) is what I have, but it's coming up as an image with 'Content' above it. @chipChocolate.py

Comment: @CraftdMC - Remove the text `Content` from the `div`s. [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/eLnz2va2/5/)

Comment: But for the .img in CSS, it only has one image, but I want 3 images. @chipChocolate.py

Comment: @CraftdMC - You'll have to add three `div`s with same classes `.img` and three different `id`s, For Instance, `id="facebook", id="twitter" id="googleplus"`. Then, in your CSS use these `id`s to set different image backgrounds. If you could, send me the links to all the images and I'll change the code for you.

Comment: Thanks! [Facebook](http://imgur.com/3Dg6jHW), [Twitter](http://imgur.com/6UEX5XE) and [Instagram](http://imgur.com/2nH87Py). @chipChocolate.py

Comment: In this fiddle, the icons show, but when you extend the 'Result' to make the icons fit horizontally, it just disappears. [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/eLnz2va2/8/) @chipChocolate.py

Comment: @CraftdMC - [Here you go](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/eLnz2va2/9/). I've fixed the problem.